# How can I enable or disable push notifications in my Xamarin application?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, monogame

I know that the user can enable or disable push notifications in the iOS/Android settings for my application. I have tried it with my application and it works.

But my question is, would it be possible that the user could enable or disable push notifications in my application so that the user doesn't need to go to the iOS/Android settings?

I use App Center Push for Xamarin iOS and Android applications.
[App Center Push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-ios)

I have tried `Push.SetEnabledAsync(false);` to disable push notifications in my application, but it's not working. The push notifications still pop up.

Is it possible to use some code in my application to disable or enable push notifications on both Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Android?

Comment: `Push.SetEnabledAsync(false);` will only disable registration for new push events, it says in the docs that it won't stop push notifications from being received from the device.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-ios#enable-or-disable-push-at-runtime

Comment: From your app, call a backend service to turn off push notification for the particular user. Thereafter don't send push notifications to disabled users from your server.